# Is there a -prune equivalent for mdfind?

Tags: macos, mdfind

Trying to find a `mdfind` equivalent to the following command.

```
find ~/Library -name "*org.virtualbox.app.VirtualBox*" -prune
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, spotlight doesn't even want to show you results in that folder, so you're not going to get good results there unless someone can show how to relax Apple's settings for your specific version / build of macOS.

You might like [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) if you can't bend `find` to meet your needs. I use all three with a strong preference for `mdfind` first, find until it annoys me, then `ag` which is awesome, I just haven't learned it enough to get over inertia of using `find` for decades.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike!